# Exact difference between Script class and Binding class in groovy

Tags: groovy

Consider this code:

```
x = 10
10.times{    
    x++
}
assert ​binding.getVariable("x") == 20
```

As far, I'm concerned this is what happening in the above code: `Script` class has a reference to the variable `x` which has value `10` and it calls the `times` closure which will access the variable `x` from `Script`. So basically the scoping of `x` is been done by `Script` class.

But I wonder when `binding` came into the picture? In sense, I haven't called `new Binding()` or anything, but still its there.

I'm bit confused with it. What is the exact use of `binding`? Does `Script` class creates `binding`, if so that is how it manages scoping of `x` within `times` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh.  I see you [simultaneously cross-posted this to the user list](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Exact-difference-between-Script-class-and-Binding-class-in-groovy-td5710950.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script class constructs a new binding when it is constructed

You can see it does it in [the constructor of Script](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java)